# why Hard Lefschetz is stated in the real coefficient in Huybrechts' complex geometry book?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry

In  Huybrechts' complex geometry book , the Hard Lefschetz theorem is stated as follows:

Proposition 3.3.13 (Hard Lefschetz theorem) Let $(X, g)$ be a compact Kähler manifold of dimension $n$. Then for $k \leq n$
$$
L^{n-k}: H^k(X, \mathbb{R}) \cong H^{2 n-k}(X, \mathbb{R})
$$
and for any $k$
$$
H^k(X, \mathbb{R})=\bigoplus_{i \geq 0} L^i H^{k-2 i}(X, \mathbb{R})_{\mathrm{p}}
$$
Moreover, both assertions respect the bidegree decomposition. In particular, $H^k(X, \mathbb{R})_{\mathrm{p}} \otimes \mathbb{C}=\bigoplus_{p+q=k} H^{p, q}(X)_{\mathrm{p}}$

Proof. The first assertion is iii) of Remark 3.2.7. (which used the isomorphism of harmonic forms).

---

There seem to have many things to talk about the coefficient of the cohomology. In the book, we use that Lefschetz operator induced isomorphism on the harmonic form to prove the statement. However, the harmonic form is defined using the complex coefficient. I was confused why we can use it for the real coefficient case?

Comment: This is (probably) because it is one of the pieces of data of a (real) Hodge structure. Variation of Hodge structure is a very important area of algebraic/complex geometry. The same result applies when the Kähler class is rational, and the cohomology is taken with rational coefficients. This is important when defining mixed Hodge structures.

Comment: @user569579 Thank you for your comment , I have a concept question that has confused me , the sheaf cohomology for $\Bbb{Z}$ is singular cohomology correct? and for $\Bbb{R}$ is the deRham cohomology for real forms correct, and for $\Bbb{C}$ is deRham cohomology for complex differential ? what's the difference between sheaf cohomology with $\Bbb{Z}$ coefficient and $\Bbb{R}$ coefficient?

Comment: Yes, you can view them in that way.

Comment: Therefore $\Bbb{Z}$ coefficient sheaf cohomology and $\Bbb{R}$ coefficient are the same ? @user569579

Comment: No, that is not true. Cohomology groups with integer coefficients might have a torsion subgroup.

Comment: But singular cohomology isomorphic to the deRham cohomology? @user569579

Comment: No, singular cohomology with real coefficients is isomorphic to de Rham cohomology. $H^k(M,\mathbb{R})\cong H^k(M,\mathbb{Z})\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{R}$. It kills off the torsion part and gives a real vector space, whose dimension is the rank of the abelian group $H^k(M,\mathbb{Z})$. This group is not a vector space so clearly they are not "the same".

Comment: Thank you , clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the completeness I write down the proof in detail.

The idea is for any real manifold, we can define the harmonic operator and the space of Harmonic form isomorphic to the deRham group with real coefficient. therefore the problem can be reduced to the problem of harmonic form.

For the Kahler setting we have the commutative relation $[L,\Delta_d]$ holds on the space $\mathcal{A}^{\cdot}_{\Bbb{C}}(X)$. However the key observation is that both $L$ and $d$ are real operator, that is if we restrict to the form with real coefficient $\mathcal{A}_{\Bbb{R}}^\cdot$ the image is still real form. $\Delta_d$ is real operator since $d$ is real operator ,$L$ is real operator since Kahler form is real (1,1) form.

Therefore we have the Kahler identity restrict to the real case. Since $L$ respect $\Delta_d$ (with real coefficient also complex coefficient), we have the isomorphism on the level of differential form $L^{n-k}: \mathcal{A}^k(X, \mathbb{R}) \cong \mathcal{A}^{2n-k}(X, \mathbb{R})
$ induce the isomorphism on the level of harmonic form.

Since harmonic form isomorphic to deRham group, we have the isomorphism on the deRham cohomology with real coefficient.

---

For the second statement, needs a little lemma: if $\alpha = \sum_i L^i \alpha_i$ being the decomposition such that $\alpha$ is harmonic form, then $\alpha_i$ is also harmonic form. This due to the fact that $\Delta_d$ commute with $L$, and the uniqueness of the decomposition.

---

For the third statement(which is called Lefschetz decomposition is compatible with the Hodge decomposition)

given $\alpha$ which is premitive k form, it has Hodge decomposition as $\alpha  = \sum_{p+q = k} \alpha^{p,q}$  then apply the $\Lambda \alpha = 0$ then it will decomposition by bidegree, as $\Lambda$ is pure type (-1,-1) therefore all $\alpha^{p,q} \in \ker \Lambda$

(Here we use a little fact that kernel of complexified map is the kernel of original map tensor with $\Bbb{C}$. You can find the result on Conrad's note Theorem 2.9. [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf) used the fact that the free module are flat.)